# Mod_Rewrite: Redirect all reqs to subdirectory so subsequent redirects don't require the subdirectory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm redirecting my root to a subdirectory on my server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_from_git/$1 [L]
```

In that subdirectory (`_from_git`/) will also be .htaccess files with redirects. I want my like below redirects to be exact matches using the start (`^`) and end (`$`) selectors, but I don't want to have to include `^_from_git/` in every rewrite.

So my question is - How can I modify my **root redirect above**, so my subsequent redirects can be
like this:

```
^old_page\.html$ /new_page.html [R=301,L]
```

and not like this:

```
^_from_git/old_page\.html$ /new_page.html [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

edit: Here you can see the location of my .htaccess files:
[image]

Root .htaccess:
[image]

Subdirectory's .htaccess:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `/_from_git/.htaccess` file then you can have these rules **without the need to prefix each rule pattern with `/_from_git/`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old_page\.html$ /new_page.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: RewriteBase /_from_git/ ?

Comment: Thanks but I've just checked and adding the "NC" flag doesn't eliminate the need for the '_from_git' in /_from_git/.htaccess

Comment: `NC` is just for ignore case not anything else :) And you removed your earlier comment before I could reply. If this .htaccess is placed in `/_from_git/` then **your rules cannot even work** like this `RewriteRule ^_from_git/old_page\.html$` because .htaccess is per directory directive and URI is matched relative to the current directory only.

Comment: @anubhava, this is what I'm currently having to do (include the ^from_git/) and it does work. I've updated the question to include a photo of my directory incase it wasnt clear from my question

Comment: Dude, there are 2 htaccess files, one in the root and one in the _from_git/ !

Comment: Screenshot is showing 2 .htaccess files actually so can't make out which rewrite rule is in which. **This is absolute core concept of `.htaccess` in Apache. `RewriteRule` matches URIs relative to the current directory only.**

Comment: Ok you've deleted that comment. Do appreciate you trying to help but can you see that this answer provides nothing useful as it's suggesting what I'm already doing?

Comment: This answer is 100% correct and there is nothing much to add. You can rename root .htaccess and then have just one rule as I showed above and it will still work with this URL `http://domain.com/_from_git/old_page.html`

Comment: I've added screenshots of my .htaccess contents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72138/discussion-between-anubhava-and-haroldo).